# Possible to connect Android device to Internet with Ethernet

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, networking

I want to connect my Samsung S3/S4 to the internet using an Ethernet cable and USB network adapter. Is this possible?

I have tried a couple different adapters, which don't work, and leads me to wonder if A. there is an adapter that works; B. If there is any software/drivers that I need; C. is there a way to do this with code?

I have gotten this to work a Nexus Tablet. I'm wondering why it works on the tablet, but not on a device.

I want to do this because I have some code that needs to be tested, and I'm looking for a way to ensure that I ALWAYS have an Internet connection. The wireless connections tend to be flaky on my network.

Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you might want to take a look into [reverse tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether).

Comment: It's not. I'm trying to avoid rooting if possible.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)